# Does an impossible value on a Confidence Interval for a probability distribution contain information?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Suppose I analyze a distribution and determine that a 95% CI for some measure is [-1, 1] (bearing in mind the actual value in this case cannot be < 0). And suppose another 95% CI for some other measure is [0,1].

Can I, based on the CI, conclude anything different for these two CIs? What if the first CI was [-100,1]?

My intuition says that, eg, the [-100,1] example i should expect a lot more values near zero than in the [0,1] example.

The question boils down to: Does a CI that contains 'impossible' values contain information **above** the tradition *interpretation* of that CI, that conducting after the experiment a lot of times, 95% pf the results will be in [0,1]?

Comment: An absurd confidence interval is just an absurd confidence interval. If something is defined only on [0, 1] and the lower 95% limit is below 0, then the absurd procedure isn't in that respect smarter than what else you know. You have spent _some_ of your 95% on a silly guess: it's like throwing money away.

Comment: Also, the point of a confidence interval is to express uncertainty about a point estimate; it doesn't provide a better point estimate than the point estimate. It is true that even with an absurd procedure the lower the lower limit the more you expect a lower value, but the estimate should be telling you that. Best just to use a procedure that respects the possible range of what you are estimating.

Comment: OK, I chose extreme examples to (badly) illustrate exremes; lets suppose it was [-0.1,1] vs [0,1]. Do those two CIs contain different information? For reference lets just assume the actual value can be in [0, inf] (it's a weight, or a time, or some other non-negative physical property).

Comment: Yes, in a sense they contain different information, but trying to work out what it is resembles trying to infer the real news from a source that you know to exaggerate wildly.

Comment: OK, so the intuitive sense that [-0.1,1] might be slightly more likely to contain values near 0 is not reasonable?

Comment: And...considering your earlier response...a CI of [-100, 1] would contain the important information that we had completely the wrong distribution?

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to be asking the same question repeatedly and I don't have different ways to answer. The main point about invalid limits is that you have the wrong procedure.

Comment: OK, I apologise if I did not seem to be taking in what you said: I take your most recent answer to mean 'yes' to it being the wrong distribution for CI (or procedure, I hope that is the correct interpretation); and 'no' to my prior question, meaning that the wrong procedure means that we can infer nothing from the CI, and the CI may itself be invalid? We can't even conclude it's 95% in [0,1]...is that right?

Comment: Thanks, but don't worry; I was puzzled, not irritated. Put it this way:  if some of the 95% interval is outside the valid range, then what is left must be less than 95%.  Think of the confidence as money to spend. Even if the expenditure is betting, putting some of your money on a horse not in the race is futile.

Comment: lol...love "putting some of your money on the horse not in the race"! That definitely helps...next time I see a 95% CI with absurd limit I will (a) conclude that it's < 95% and (b) I should use a different process to derive a better CI. Does this mean that the people who say "just drop the invalid range" are wrong? There seems to be a lot of advice of that type, eg. https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/SticiGui/Text/confidenceIntervals.htm (just search for "negative"). I can't help but feel there is important information lost when a range is truncated to look less absurd.

Comment: Depends on the audience. Ignoring the irrelevant bit beats taking it seriously, but I think such advice when it comes from highly competent sources such as that you give rests on not wanting to explain the more complicated procedure, or not wanting to explain it right now for the level of student. Thus a normal-based interval for a positive number or for a proportion might dip just below 0 and we might decide just to ignore that detail.

Comment: Or we use something else. The case of a confidence interval for a proportion is instructive. I like the Jeffreys or Wilson methods, but others prefer the Agresti-Coull. method as working well usually, and as easier to explain what you do. The discussion at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1009213286 is superb.

Comment: Yes, impossible (wrong) confidence intervals do contain information, but it is wrong information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confidence intervals are formed by the "inversion" of probability statements about pivotal quantities.  There are a few ways you can get a confidence interval that encompasses impossible values for the parameter it is estimating.  One common way this occurs is when you use an *approximation* to the true distribution of the pivotal quantity (e.g., an asymptotic approximation) to form the interval.  The approximating distribution may give a non-zero probability of values outside the true support of the pivotal quantity, so that when you "invert" the probability statement, you get impossible values for the parameter in the confidence interval.

So, what does this mean?  Obviously the impossible values are impossible, so you can (and should) reduce your confidence interval to only include the possible values of the parameter.  If you get a confidence interval $\text{CI}=[-1,1]$ for a parameter that is known to be non-negative, then you should certainly adjust that to the interval $\text{CI}=[0,1]$.  However, the very fact that you are getting a substantial amount of coverage of values that are impossible is a **big flashing warning sign** that the distribution approximation underlying our interval is not very good, and so the confidence interval is not trustworthy.  In practice, if you get a confidence interval like this, you should change your method to use an alternative interval that does not use an approximation for the distribution of the pivotal quantity.

A simple example of this is when you generate a confidence interval for the probability parameter in an IID Bernoulli model.  If you use the normal approximation to the sample proportion then you get a confidence interval that can give bounds that are outside the range $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 1$.  However, if you use the Wilson score interval then this always respects the possible range of the parameter.

Comment: I take it from this answer that the only information that an impossible CI range gives is how bad the approximation was in the first place. Which make me worried about the blanket advice to remove impossible values....it's a great way to disguise the fact that bad modelling was used!

Comment: As with all accountable statistical work, in the event that impossible parts of the CI are removed, that should be *disclosed* in the analysis.  It would indeed be bad practice if a poor CI was used, and then adjusted for impossibility without disclosing this to the reader.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back; I like the notion that the full CI bounds should be disclosed when unrealistic. Is there any simple rule that might be applied (like the np|nq rule for binomlial approximation)? eg. [-0.1, 10] (for < 0 unreal) seems more or less harmless, whereas [-0.5,1] would seem to be extremely dubious.

Comment: The simple rule I always go by is: What would I want to know if I were the reader?

Answer (score 3):

Some of the confidence intervals for binomial success probability $p$ are derived
from asymptotic expressions and they should not be expected to work well for small $n.$
As an example, suppose I observe $n=15$ binomial trials and find $X = 1$ Success.

The Wald CI, based on an asymptotic argument, uses point estimate $\hat p = x/n = 1/15.$
Then the 95% Wald CI is of the form $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}.$
Thich computes (in R) to $(-.06,0.19),$ which goes outside the interval $(0,1).$
[Among statisticians who are somehow fixated on use of the Wald interval, this
inappropriate result might be reported as $(0, 0.19),$ which is not exactly true
and does nothing to help the poor overall performance of the Wald interval for small $n.]$

```
n = 15;  x = 1
p.hat = x/n
CI.w = p.hat + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)
CI.w
[1] -0.05956701  0.19290034
```

By contrast, the 95% Agresti-Coull CI 'shrinks toward 1/2' to get more accurate
coverage probability. (It is mentioned in one of the more recent Comments of @NickCox.) It uses the point estimate $\tilde p = (x+2)/(x+4)$ and
a 95% CI is of the form $\tilde p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\tilde p(1-\tilde p)}{n+4}}.$
This interval is $(-.01, 0.32).$ It goes very slightly outside $(0,1)$ and the procedure overall comes closer to 95% coverage of $p$ than does the Wald interval.
[The appending of 2 Successes and 2 Failures to the data may seem strange, but is a 'trick' that happens to make the Agresti interval closer to the somewhat more accurate Wilson interval. The trick works only for 95% CIs because it conflate 1.96 with 2.]

```
n = 15;  x = 1
p.est = (x+2)/(n+4)
CI.a = p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/(n+4))
CI.a
[1] -0.006065414  0.321854887
```

The Jeffreys CI is based on a Bayesian argument, but has very good frequentist
properties. For most $n$ and values of $p,$ it comes closer to giving 95% coverage.
For 95% coverage, this interval uses quantiles $.025$, and $0.975$ of the
distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(x+.5, n-x + .5).$
If you have access to software it is easy to compute, as shown below.
The result is $(0.01, 0.27),$ which is usually close to the Agresti interval and, for
out example,
entirely contained in $(0, 1).$ [The Bayesian argument starts with a beta prior distribution which has support $(0,1)$ and thus cannot possibly give results outside
that interval.]

```
n = 15;  x = 1
CI.j = qbeta(c(.025,.975), x+.5, n-x+.5)
[1] 0.007290218 0.271751314
```

Suppose that $n = 15$ and $p = 0.1.$ Here is a brief simulation showing
the probabilities that 95% CIs due to Wald (94%), Agresti (55%), and Jeffreys (0%) have negative lower confidence limits. [On average the lower confidence limits for the three types of CIs are about $-0.03, 0.01, 0.02,$
respectively.]

```
set.seed(2020)
n = 15
x = rbinom(10^6, n, .1)

p.hat = x/n 
lcl.w = p.hat - 1.96*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)
mean(lcl.w < 0)
[1] 0.739258

p.est = (x+2)/(n+4)
lcl.a = p.est - 1.96*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/(n+4))
mean(lcl.a < 0)
[1] 0.549227

lcl.j = qbeta(.025, x+.5, n-x+.5)
mean(lcl.j < 0)
[1] 0

mean(lcl.w); mean(lcl.a); mean(lcl.j)
[1] -0.02792535
[1] 0.01344886
[1] 0.02395252
```

*Note:* The Project Euclid article linked by @NickCox is somewhat similar to
Brown, Cai, and DasGupta (2001), "Interval estimates for binomial proportion," *Statistical Science,* **16,** 101-133.

Comment: "somewhat similar" here means "identical".

Comment: @NickCox: Thanks. They certainly looked at _lot_ the same, but I didn't do a section by section comparison, so settled for 'somewhat similar'.

Comment: This gives excellent detail on estimating a proportion, but the question is much more general.